# $.load() pushes footer off page

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a page which loads a header and footer using jQuery load(). I use 2 divs and load the content into them:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#header").load("header.html");
        $("#footer").load("footer.html");
    });
<script>
<body>
    <div>
         <div id="header"></div>
         <div id="content">
         <!--page content-->
         </div>
         <div id="footer"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Footer.html

```
<footer class="main-footer">
    <!-- To the right -->
    <div class="pull-right hidden-xs">
      <b>Version</b> 1.0
    </div>
    <!-- Default to the left -->
    <strong>Company name</strong>
</footer>
```

Before I broke out the header and the footer from their own files the page loaded fine. Now, when I load the footer gets pushed just off the bottom of the page causing the page to scroll. The footer doesn't always need to be visible but it should be just at the bottom if the page content doesn't fill the screen.

I believe this is happening because the page content filling the window then the footer is being appended to the bottom rather than the footer loading with the page content. How can I get the footer to stop being pushed off the bottom of the screen?

---

**Solution:** First, I removed the div tags and replaced them with footer and header tags. Then I removed the footer and header tags from the footer.html and header.html files. Finally, I edited the style sheets to include a min-height in both the footer and header. Adding the min-height allocated space for the footer and header and they no longer are pushed off screen.

Comment: Can you please provide your whole page, header and footer HTML files and complete js code?

Comment: So how are you positioning the footer at the bottom of the page?

Comment: If I replace the footer div with the footer code it works fine.

Comment: Sounds like a pure CSS issue. Note that `load()` inserts _inside_ the element, it doesn't replace it. Now you have `<div>`s stuck in between your `<header>` and `<footer>` it is probably breaking whatever header/footer CSS layout you had. Can you add the CSS for these?

Comment: @Rhumborl Thats what I thought at first. For testing I put the footer code between the divs and it works. Also I tried using the footer tags in place of the divs but I run into the same problem.

Comment: So are you positioning the footer with Javascript? and is this running before the header and footer responses come back and the elements are populated?

Comment: I commented out the header load and the page loads fine. It appears my issue is the header pushing down the page content.